# Use of namespace in MathML rendering

Tags: javascript, html, namespaces, mathjax

Now mathMLs without namespace are rending fine, but if I am adding namespace like m: or mml: then rendering not working. Any help Thanks in advance.

Below is the code I have used.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:/P:/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h3>MathML Previewer</h3>

        Paste your MathML:<br/>
            <textarea id="myMath" style="resize: none; height:250px; width:850px">
        </textarea>

            <button type="button" onclick="myclear()">Reset</button>
            <p>Click the button to get output</p>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Output</button>
            <div id="demo">
            </div>

            <script>
                function myFunction() {

                var x = document.getElementById("myMath").value;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
                MathJax.Hub.Typeset("demo");
                }
            </script>
            <script>
                function myclear() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myMath").value =' ';
                //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

                }
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

MathML:

With namespace not rendering

```
 <m:math display="block" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><m:mrow><m:mi>r</m:mi><m:mo>=</m:mo><m:mfrac><m:mrow><m:mstyle displaystyle='true'><m:mo>&#x03A3;</m:mo><m:mrow><m:mi>x</m:mi><m:mi>y</m:mi><m:mo>-</m:mo><m:mfrac><m:mrow><m:mo stretchy='false'>(</m:mo><m:mstyle displaystyle='true'><m:mo>&#x03A3;</m:mo><m:mi>x</m:mi></m:mstyle><m:mo stretchy='false'>)</m:mo><m:mo stretchy='false'>(</m:mo><m:mstyle displaystyle='true'><m:mo>&#x03A3;</m:mo><m:mi>y</m:mi></m:mstyle><m:mo stretchy='false'>)</m:mo></m:mrow><m:mi>n</m:mi></m:mfrac></m:mrow></m:mstyle></m:mrow><m:mrow><m:msqrt><m:mrow><m:mstyle displaystyle='true'><m:mo>&#x03A3;</m:mo><m:mrow><m:msup><m:mi>x</m:mi><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:msup><m:mo>-</m:mo><m:mfrac><m:mrow><m:msup><m:mrow><m:mo stretchy='false'>(</m:mo><m:mstyle displaystyle='true'><m:mo>&#x03A3;</m:mo><m:mi>x</m:mi></m:mstyle><m:mo stretchy='false'>)</m:mo></m:mrow><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:msup></m:mrow><m:mi>n</m:mi></m:mfrac></m:mrow></m:mstyle></m:mrow></m:msqrt></m:mrow></m:mfrac></m:mrow></m:math>
```

Without namespace rendering as required.

```
 <math display="block" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mi>r</mi><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mrow><mstyle displaystyle='true'><mo>&#x03A3;</mo><mrow><mi>x</mi><mi>y</mi><mo>-</mo><mfrac><mrow><mo stretchy='false'>(</mo><mstyle displaystyle='true'><mo>&#x03A3;</mo><mi>x</mi></mstyle><mo stretchy='false'>)</mo><mo stretchy='false'>(</mo><mstyle displaystyle='true'><mo>&#x03A3;</mo><mi>y</mi></mstyle><mo stretchy='false'>)</mo></mrow><mi>n</mi></mfrac></mrow></mstyle></mrow><mrow><msqrt><mrow><mstyle displaystyle='true'><mo>&#x03A3;</mo><mrow><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>-</mo><mfrac><mrow><msup><mrow><mo stretchy='false'>(</mo><mstyle displaystyle='true'><mo>&#x03A3;</mo><mi>x</mi></mstyle><mo stretchy='false'>)</mo></mrow><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mi>n</mi></mfrac></mrow></mstyle></mrow></msqrt></mrow></mfrac></mrow></math>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the namespaces to be processed properly, you need to declare them in the `<html>` tag. E.g.,

```
<html xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
```

If you want to process both m: and mml:, add both as namsepaces.

```
<html xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
```

This is necessary for XHTML documents, but not for HTML5.

Comment: Dear Sir, though I have added both namespaces but rendering ouput is not as that of without namespace.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not the same.  The page works for me (once I remove the extra `</div>` and convert `<br>` to `<br/>` to make if valid XHTML).  Also, it looks like you are using this through a `file://` URL, but you haven't said whether you are using a file with name ending in `.xhtml` or just `.html`.  They both work as expected for me.  If you are continuing to have problems, you might need to post the MathML that is not rendering for you as well as the code above.

Comment: I have added the mathml codes in the question above sir.

Comment: Yes, and it works for me.  If it is not working for you, you need to explain more clearly what is not working for you.  That should include the MathML that you are typing, and the browser and OS that you are using.  When you say "rendering output is not as that of without namespace", what does that *mean*?  What specifically is wrong with the output?

Comment: Dear Sir, I am using firefox browser 14.0.1. MathML with namespace rendering in a single line which is not correct. MathML without namespace rendering the actual view.

Comment: When you say "which is not correct", in what way is it flawed?  Does it not render at all, or is the layout incorrect in some way (please specify)?  Also, Firefox is now at version 32, so you are using a *very* old version of Firefox.  Perhaps upgrading would help.  Both your examples render for me in Firefox 31 on Mac OS X.  Finally, you are using a local copy of MathJax; what version is that?  Have you tried using the CDN copy to see if that works?  What OS are you using?

Comment: Dear sir, though it is rendering but the layout is not correct. I mean to say not that of without namespace. I am using Windows 8 OS and MathJax version 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue today. As stated previously you have declare the namespaces before using them. Adding namespaces to math tags does not work in html only in xhtml - with declaration of the namespace within the html tag. Make sure the file has the **.xhtml** extension.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" async="async"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Quadratic Equation</h3>
  <math>
  <m:mi>x</m:mi> <m:mo>=</m:mo>
  <m:mrow>
    <m:mfrac>
      <m:mrow>
        <m:mo>&#x2212;</m:mo>
        <m:mi>b</m:mi>
        <m:mo>&#x00B1;</m:mo>
        <m:msqrt>
          <m:msup><m:mi>b</m:mi><mn>2</mn></m:msup>
          <m:mo>&#x2212;</m:mo>
          <mn>4</mn><m:mi>a</m:mi><m:mi>c</m:mi>
        </m:msqrt>
      </m:mrow>
      <m:mrow> <mn>2</mn><m:mi>a</m:mi> </m:mrow>
    </m:mfrac>
  </m:mrow>
</math>
</body>
</html>
```